# React Native "GET /onchange HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "okhttp/3.6.0" log after react native update

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've just updated from react native version 0.55 to 0.57.

After I start the project,

I keep on getting this log 
`[20:04:52] ::ffff:(IP address) - - [03/Nov/2018:11:04:52 +0000] "GET /onchange HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "okhttp/3.6.0"
[20:05:02] ::ffff:(IP address) - - [03/Nov/2018:11:05:02 +0000] "GET /onchange HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "okhttp/3.6.0"
[20:05:13] ::ffff:(IP address) - - [03/Nov/2018:11:05:13 +0000] "GET /onchange HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "okhttp/3.6.0"
[20:05:23] ::ffff:(IP address) - - [03/Nov/2018:11:05:23 +0000] "GET /onchange HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "okhttp/3.6.0"
[20:05:33] ::ffff:(IP address) - - [03/Nov/2018:11:05:33 +0000] "GET /onchange HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "okhttp/3.6.0"`

on console.log every 10 seconds. The project works fine though. What is this and why is this outputted on the console log? can i disable it?

Comment: I face the same issue. I don't know what is that and the solution. If found solution, please write here. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue. The problem is with the **version** of the expo-cli / react-native-cli you are using. My problem is solved after upgrading to the latest version. Try to upgrade your cli. If the problem still exists, try to upgrade your npm to the latest version and cache verify and then install the latest cli again.